# Can creating a method scoped variable for the return value have any downside in Java?

Tags: java, compiler-optimization

I often use a method scoped variable in order to store the return value in order to make the use of conditional debugger breakpoints more easy:

```
boolean retValue = some very complex condition;
return retValue;
```

instead of

```
return some very complex condition;
```

because they I can just set `!retValue` as breakpoint condition and don't even need to maintain that condition after changing `some very complex condition`. The same applies to return values different from `boolean` which might be initialized in a different way.

Is there any possibility that such variables are not removed by the Java compiler when compiling with optimization?

I'm aware that this is considered Code smell because `retValue` might unintentionally be overwritten which could be prevented with `final`.

Comment: I am quite confident that the JIT compiler will optimize this when it deems it necessary. So write what you prefer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any possibility that such variables are not removed by the Java compiler when compiling with optimization?

Even if they aren't, it's completely irrelevant. You wouldn't notice it in any way. Being concerned with something like this smells of micro-optimization.

Also `javac` does very little optimization itself. It's the JIT compiler that will try to make your code efficient.

---

The basic flow is this: write correct, well designed, readable code. **If** you notice an issue with performance, it will be a lot easier to fix when your software is built on a sturdy foundation.

You also won't be wasting time on trying to speed up things that don't need to be sped up.

Answer (score -1):

Java has a built in garbage collector, so a memory leak isnt a risk. Regardless of if you allocate a memory address to contain some very complex condition, Java will take care of it with the garbage collector, since that temporary variable is never used again.

Comment: Please don't confuse things. In this case, possible space for holding boolean is allocated on the stack, so there is no GC involved at any point in any JVM.

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski why are you talking about `boolean` values? OP did not say anything of the return type. If an object is returned, TinFellow's statement is true.

Comment: `boolean retValue =` kind of hints at small boolean result... and even if we assume that it is not boolean, but some kind of Object, then above statement is not neccessarily true, as non-optimizing interpreter can easily keep that object referenced till the end of method, which might never happen (so statement about variable being never used again allowing GC to happen is not universally true).

Comment: whoopsie =) I actually overread that part. @TinFellow: a comment mentioning that GC is only responsible for Heap-objects would be beneficial.